# CORS: Have Facebook enabled CORS for all of its pictures?

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, canvas, cors

I've read somewhere that Facebook have cross enabled for Profile Pictures. I'm not sure about albums and other stuff, but in fact Facebook is including the header  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on every one of the URLs that I have tested to far.

I've tried the standard Profile picture URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/picture?width=25&height=25
```

And well as Akamai urls:

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/...
```

(The latter are returned by `https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/photos`)

---

My app is basically doing things such as:

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/...";
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}

// Above code will be repeated several times
// And mixed with code that manipulates ctx 

// Finally generetes data 
var generatedImage = canvas.toDataURL();
// And post if back to Facebook
```

Everything seems to be working fine with my code (tested on all major browsers), but there are a lot of users reporting intermittent bugs when uploading the canvas content back to Facebook. 
Unfortunately I couldn't yet get a tech savvy user to report something with a proper error description. Now I can't reproduce the problem (or even know what the problem is).

What I know so far is that by writing a server side proxy to serve Facebook images as if they were local the bugs apparently go away, so, it left me wondering, before I start digging into bizarre cross-browser issues, mysterious error messages such as `OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred.`, tainted cavas, etc, I first have to go back to the basics:

Is CORS enabled for every single picture exposed through Graph API? (A link to the official documentation or a reliable source would be nice).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23123261/1475331

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Again answering my own question.

Apparently **yes**, CORS is enabled for every picture exposed through the Graph API. They are all being returned with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

It seems like some browsers do not play well with `crossorigin='anonymous'` and CORS headers, so, for now, a proxy service is still the safe way to go.

Comment: Do you know which browsers don't support cross-origin images drawn to canvas then the data pulled out?