# Webgl Cross Origin Images don't work

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, cors, webgl

I've got some problem with cross-origin image and I hope you can help.

Here the beahviour.
I've got 2 domains, in example:
- domain1.com
- domain2.com

On domain1 I put many html5 games. This domain is only a repository of games.

Domain2 is the real website (wordpress website) where users can play games hosted on domain1.
To doing this I made a curl request for every game.

In domain1 nginx configuration file I put these lines of code for enabling Cross Origin Resource Sharing:

```
    location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|json|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|mp3|xml|woff2)$ {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }
```

This resolved some issues for many games but some games are still not working and I get this js error:

```
    Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/images/loadingbarbackground-sheet0.png may not be loaded.
        at GLWrap_.loadTexture (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:2618:16)
        at pluginProto.Type.typeProto.loadTextures (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:18070:46)
        at pluginProto.Instance.instanceProto.onCreate (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:18146:13)
        at Runtime.createInstanceFromInit (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:4806:8)
        at Layer.createInitialInstances (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:7541:25)
        at Layout.startRunning (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:6715:10)
        at Runtime.go_loading_finished (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:4067:36)
        at Runtime.go (http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:3966:9)
        at http://domain1.com/html5-games/action/candy-match/c2runtime.js:4025:60
```

I made some research online and I found articles like these
https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html
[Drawing images to canvas with img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123237/drawing-images-to-canvas-with-img-crossorigin-anonymous-doesnt-work)

but they are not very helpful.

I wouldn't like to modify original game files. I'm looking for a server side solution if it exists. If not, have you got some idea for resolve my problem?

Is there some error in my configuration? Am I missing something?

Thank you for the help.

Valerio

Comment: Have you checked via your browser dev tools, whether your server for domain1 actually returns the correct headers?

Comment: Hi @CBroe apparently headers seems ok.HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 09:33:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 4431
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 08:00:45 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "59ca092d-114f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

Comment: I meant for the images ...

Comment: Uh sorry @CBroe , here headers i get for the image https://imgur.com/a/huxPq

Comment: Hm, that looks okay, at least in regard to the CORS header. Probably some issue with the code then. If modifying that is out of the question, then I think you might have to refrain from using cross-origin images here at all; unless you were willing to proxy them through the domain1 server ...

Comment: Try setting the access-control header to the actual domain instead of wildcard, also maybe try another browser for a more detailed error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The games have to request cross origin images. Simply returning the correct headers is not enough. If the games themselves don't request cross origin images by setting the `crossOrigin` attribute then the browser will not allow the images to be used even if they have the correct headers.

Here's an example

```js
const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

loadImage('https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png', false);
loadImage('https://i.imgur.com/u6VI8xz.jpg', true);

function loadImage(url, crossOrigin) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => { upload(img); };
  if (crossOrigin) {
    img.crossOrigin = '';
  }
  img.src = url;
}

function upload(img) {
  // trap for cors error
  try {
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    log(img.src, "uploaded image");
  } catch (e) {
    log(img.src, e);
  }
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

And here you can see even those the first image returned the CORS headers it was not allowed to be used because `crossOrigin` was not set

[image]

The second image has the same headers but it works because we set the `crossOrigin` attribute

[image]

Note that you **might** be able to include a script like this before the game scripts to kind of hack in CORS support.

```
(function() {

function isSameOrigin(url) {
  return (new URL(url, window.location.href)).origin === window.location.origin;
}

function needsCORS(url) {
  // not sure all the URLs that should be checked for
  return !isSameOrigin(url) && !url.startsWith("blob:") && !url.startsWith("data:");
}

const srcSetFn = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'src').set; 

Object.defineProperty(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'src', {
  enumerable: true,
  set: function(url) {
     if (needsCORS(url)) {
       // Set if not already set
       if (this.crossOrigin !== undefined) {
         this.crossOrigin = '';
       }
     } else {
       this.crossOrigin = undefined;
     }
     // Set the original attribute
     srcSetFn.call(this, url);
  },
});

}());
```

Answer (score -1):

http://webgl-hooman.blogspot.ca/2018/01/cross-origin-image-cannot-be-loaded-in.html

CORS = Cross Origin Resource Sharing. It's a way for the webpage to ask the image server for permission to use the image.​ The cross origin is the security protection that is built in Google Chrome not allowing users to have access to local files (in this case your image/texture). Even in Safari, you will get "the operation is insecure" error. You have couple of options. The easiest way is to have your webgl application runs from a web server such as IIS or Apache. The other option is to open your webgl applications using Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge browsers if you are using Windows. If you are running your webgl application from Mac using "FireFox" browser, add crossorigin="anonymous" to your image tag in HTML where your texture is getting loaded. But this won't work if you are using "Windows" operating system or any other browsers even in Mac! It only works with MAC+Firefox. So either change your image tag to this   or simple add this var image = document.getElementById("texImage"); image.crossOrigin = ""; More on this, read: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html